# Tag name applies to the question, but tag definition doesn't: remove tag?

Tags: support, tags, edits

Recently I removed the tag [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton) from a [Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info) question ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703419/squeeze-some-of-singleton-dimensions-in-matlab)). I considered the tag was being used incorrectly, because the OP meant *singleton dimension* (for example, a matrix of size 3x1 has a singleton dimension, namely the second), whereas the [tag definition](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/singleton/info) refers to the *object-oriented concept of singleton* (it says "The singleton is a design pattern to ensure that exactly one application-wide instance of a particular class exists").

But then again, after discussing the matter with a fellow answerer, I'm not sure. Perhaps it *is* correct to keep the tag because its *name* applies to the question very well (although its definition doesn't).

What do you think? What's the appropriate action here?

Comment: Remove. Most of the value of a tag comes from the people following it, who will generally do so because of its "official" meaning. I doubt anybody following `singleton` had the singleton dimension in mind...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally the tag wiki counts. If it states that it should be applied to questions with a certain topic, then it should be removed from questions which are unrelated.

For very generic terms this could be an issue and one could consider renaming the tag to make it less ambiguous. However, for a programming oriented site like Stack Overflow, I'd say that Singleton's meaning is pretty clear, and I don't see much of a practical conflict with a singleton dimension, nor do I see the need to create another tag specifically for that case.

So yes, removing it from the question was the proper action.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes much sense to me. Let's see if there are other opinions, though

Comment: Sure @LuisMendo. */me grabs smiting stick in anticipation*